# Group objects in array by property value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm sure something similar has already been asked here, so I apologize in advance if this is redundant, but i did look and didn't find something that fit my specific needs. Hoping someone can help.

I have an array of pageSections:

```
const sections = [
  {
    data: { 
      order: 0, 
      title: "home_hero", 
      block_type: "hero", 
      pages: ["home"]       
    },
  },
  {
    data: {
      order: 0,
      title: "about_hero",
      block_type: "hero",
      pages: ["about"],
    },
  },
  {
    data: {
      order: 1,
      title: "home_intro",
      block_type: "content_block",
      pages: ["home"],
    },
  },
  {
    data: {
      order: 0,
      title: "service_card1",
      block_type: "card",
      pages: ["home", "services"],
    },
  },
  {
    data: {
      order: 1,
      title: "service_card2",
      block_type: "card",
      pages: ["home", "services"],
    },
  },
  {
    data: {
      order: 2,
      title: "service_card3",
      block_type: "card",
      pages: ["home", "services"],
    },
  },
];
```

I'd like to group the each of the sections that are card blocks together into their own array on the same original array. So that the end result would be something like this:

```
const sections = [
  {
    data: {
      order: 0,
      title: "home_hero",
      block_type: "hero",
      pages: ["home"],
    },
  },
  {
    data: {
      order: 0,
      title: "about_hero",
      block_type: "hero",
      pages: ["about"],
    },
  },
  {
    data: {
      order: 1,
      title: "home_intro",
      block_type: "content_block",
      pages: ["home"],
    },
  },
  [
    {
      data: {
        order: 0,
        title: "service_card1",
        block_type: "card",
        pages: ["home", "services"],
      },
    },
    {
      data: {
        order: 1,
        title: "service_card2",
        block_type: "card",
        pages: ["home", "services"],
      },
    },
    {
      data: {
        order: 2,
        title: "service_card3",
        block_type: "card",
        pages: ["home", "services"],
      },
    },
  ],
];
```

I'm pretty sure that i'd need to use some combination of reduce, map and filter, but cannot seem to wrap my head around it. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm pretty confident that there would be a way to do this in one line, but I couldn't figure it out.

But, here is a 2-lined solution that achieves what you want:

```
let grouped = sections.filter(section => section.data.block_type !== "card");
grouped.push(sections.filter(section => section.data.block_type == "card"));
```

Answer (score -1):

one-liner + optimal

```js
Array.prototype.concat(
    sections.filter(s => s.data.block_type !== "card"),
    sections.filter(s => s.data.block_type == "card")
);
```

On the other hand, this creates **a new array**, from **2 other new arrays** originating from the source. I don't argue with the use case, but it seems pretty rare. There surely is a better way to achieve whatever end result you're looking for.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! I'm definitely open to any suggestions for "better ways" of achieving this end result. Care to elaborate? Thanks again!

Comment: Well, it mostly depends on.. where is that data coming from? You manually crafting it... is it a crud operation, the result of a query? What script are you feeding it into, and can that script be adapted to work with the data as it is, without transforming it. It all depends on your architecture, but if it were me, and i would need to map === "card" and !== "card", i would probably feed my script a reference to the unchanged original array, and a map of indexes.

Comment: The data is coming from a github folder, that is brought in via an api request.  The folder is a flat representations of each section in my site as I could not figure out how to recursively grab the data for each page from github's AST. So the data could definitely be more amiable. It's just my limitations of knowledge and time in order to work with it properly. Just in case you or anyone here has any familiarity I'm using the octockit/rest package to facilitate the requests. I think in a later version I might introduce their graphql package instead, as I'm still just fleshing out this concept

Comment: here's a thought
`const map = sections.map(s => s.data.block_type !== "card" ? 0 : 1);`

feed the map to your script along with sections, and whenever you need to do something just with items that satisfy === "block", like rendering something, you can parse the map instead of the original array, and you can use the index in the map to pick the actual object inside `sections`